# Confusion about mac find command man page

Tags: linux, bash, macos

While in the `find` manual page, the Synopsis part says:

```
SYNOPSIS

 find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx]
      [-f path] path ...
      [expression]
```

And i want to find all files whose name contains "optimizing" in the current directory, so i go with this command:

```
find -E -f . -iregex ".*optimizing.*"
```

I think this match the synopsis requirements, `-E` for `extended regex`, `-f .` for `[-f path]` part
But the output says:

```
find: -f .: unknown primary or operator
```

But if i remove the `-f` options, and run this: `find -E . -iregex ".*optimizing.*"`. It would run as expected.

And dose the `SYNOPSIS` part followed the regex grammar? That is, dose `[-EXdsx]` means i can use any character in `-EXdsx` in that part?

These really confused me, and make reading man page a really horrible thing for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferent) OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the synopsis carefully

```
SYNOPSIS
     find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
```

indicates that `-f path` should be followed by another `path`, or you can omit the `-f`.

The syntax is loosely based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form